# Pointer arithmetic on pointers to variably-modified types

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Is the following valid C code? ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ovr15q))

```c
#include <stddef.h>

ptrdiff_t f(size_t n, void *x, void *y)
{
    if (!n) return 0;
    typedef unsigned char element[n];
    element *a = x, *b = y;
    return a - b;
}
```

With `-Werror=pointer-arith` clang loudly complains about

```
<source>:8:14: error: subtraction of pointers to type 'element' (aka 'unsigned char [n]') of zero size has undefined behavior [-Werror,-Wpointer-arith]
    return a - b;
           ~ ^ ~
```

while gcc compiles the code without complaint.

What is the undefined behavior that clang thinks is occuring? The
possibility of the subtraction being zero and therefore not a valid
pointer to an element of the array or something different? There's no
array access being performed, right? So that shouldn't be the case...

If the code does exhibit undefined behavior, is there a simple way to
modify the code to be fully conforming, while still using pointers to
VM-types?

Comment: What would the function return if you passed a value of zero for `n`?

Comment: I believe clang is complaining about the potential case of `n = 0`. What is it you're trying to accomplish subtracting pointers to these types though? I would imagine the padding would be platform-dependent and the difference would be unreliable.

Comment: Is there a call to `f()` in the same TU?  I assume not, but just checking.

Comment: clang complains even when considering that case. I'm adding a naive early return to the code and the motivation for trying to use this construct. And actually I'm not sure if there is a call to the function in the same TU...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'm only using `f()` as a simple test case for pointer arithmetic on pointers to VM-types, not in the source itself. Would an example of `qsort` implemented in this way help clarify what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: I suspected that you'd shown the complete TU, but I was double checking.  Methinks it might be a misinterpretation by clang.  But I need to spend more time looking at it more carefully.

Comment: Seems like a bug in clang's handling of VLA's. The `typedef` is not the issue. Declaring `a` and `b` as `unsigned char (*a)[n] = x, (*b)[n] = y;` gives the same behavior. And the program generates valid outputs if you ignore the warning (i.e. remove the `-Werror` flag).

Comment: I doubt that `qsort` is using pointers like `unsigned char (*a)[n]`, since VLA's didn't exist when `qsort` was first developed. Instead, `qsort` would use a simple `unsigned char *p`, and then do the pointer arithmetic itself, e.g. `p = p + n` to move to the next element of the array, or `unsigned char *q = p + i*n` to point `q` at the ith element of the array.

Comment: @user3386109: Nobody said they did, and it is not relevant.

Comment: @EricPostpischil *"Would an example of `qsort` implemented in this way help clarify what I'm trying to accomplish?"* and *"is there a simple way to modify the code to be fully conforming?"*

Comment: @user3386109: Yes, note the subjunctive. There is no assertion that `qsort` was implemented that way in the past. OP is asking about the code they presented and using `qsort` as an example of how it might be used. It would be new code.

Comment: This can be reproduced with `int f(void *x) { int n = 1; return (char (*)[n]) x - (char (*)[n]) x; }`. It appears to be a bug in Clang. Interestingly, `(char (*)[n]) x + 1` does not yield an error, so Clang does not universally think `char (*)[n]` has zero size. And that supports the conjecture it is a bug, since any C rules about pointer arithmetic on `char (*)[n]` should apply to adding a pointer and an integer similarly to subtracting two pointers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah, so you're just nitpicking. Clearly a *"`qsort` implemented this way"* doesn't have any value, since it will generate the exact same warning. But the original `qsort` implementation *is* instructive, since it shows how to implement the desired functionality without triggering the bug.

Comment: @user3386109: The OP and most of the commenters here do not need such instruction; they are well familiar with pointer arithmetic. Even were they not, instructing them on such pointer arithmetic does not serve the goal, which is to establish whether there is some problem in C semantics with this particular expression or some bug in Clang regarding it. That is the issue: What do C semantics say about this, and why is Clang behaving this way. The issue is not how to do the pointer arithmetic. Note the language-lawyer tag: The subject is formal C semantics.

Comment: Clang -Werror=pointer-arith also appears to fail with the example from the standard at 6.5.6/10 ("Pointer arithmetic is well defined with pointers to variable length array types.") so I don't see how it can not be a bug.

Comment: Aside: The compilation bug of `void *part()` not returning anything distracts from the question's goal.  Posting the body of `part` is not even needed as the issue is demo'd in `qsort()`.

Comment: Re: Aside: What do you mean by not returning anything? It does in `if (i >= j) return &base[j];`. I've briefly tested the code and it does produce a working sort function on gcc. You might have to redirect `qsort` to a name not in the C library's reserved namespace. `#undef qsort`, followed by `#define qsort my_qsort` after the `#include` line should do the trick to be able to compile on a hosted implementation. Does the compiler you're using think the loop in `part` is infinite or what's going on?

Comment: The solution to the `qsort` example is to `return j` from the partition function. The recursive calls become `qsort(base, j+1, bytes, cmp)` and `qsort(base+j+1, num-1-j, bytes, cmp)`. That eliminates the troublesome pointer subtraction. It may also have better performance, since pointer subtraction has an implicit division, and I don't think that division can be optimized when subtracting VLA pointers.

Comment: @user3386109 that indeed looks like a workaround to the clang error in
the example and possibly more performant to boot, thanks. I initially
had a go in the same direction but was too focused on getting the
pointer differences to work to come up with the same. And I can do
pretty much the same thing in my non-example code as a workaround.
However the questions remain if 1. clang has a bug here and 2. if
constructing "element"-pointers and using them for mere arithmetic
purposes like this is standards-conform. Any ideas?

Comment: @nebel [The comment by @ rici](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64949298/pointer-arithmetic-on-pointers-to-variably-modified-types?noredirect=1#comment114828833_64949298) is the most convincing proof you're going to get that this is a bug in clang. Hence 1. Yes, it's a bug and 2. using `element` pointers is standards compliant. However, those `element` pointers are using VLA syntax, and support for VLA syntax is **optional** as of C11. So, compliant: Yes, portable: No, compilers are allowed to reject that code.

Comment: I've removed the larger example code as it is distracting from the actual question.

Comment: @nebel What version of the C standard are you compiling against (i.e. `-std` option), and what version of clang are you using?

Comment: @dbush Any implementation that supports VLAs and any C standard that has them, optional or not (i.e. language-lawyer tag). Also see the godbolt link in the question. clang is pretty consistent on erroring out on this code since 3.4.1 inclusive, earlier versions accept the code.

Answer (score 2):

The code posted is valid C code if VLAs are supported by your compiler. Note that VLAs introduced in C99 have become optional in the latest version of the C Standard.

Both **gcc** and **clang** compile the code correctly as can be verified using [Godbolt's compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/E67hGh).

Yet **clang** issues a warning regarding potential undefined behavior if the value of the `n` argument happens to be null, failing to identify that this case has been handled with an explicit test. The problem is not the value of the subtraction but the size of the type, which would be `0` if `n == 0`. This warning is not really a bug, more a quality of implementation issue.

It is also arguable that `a - b` is only defined if both `a` and `b` point to the same array or just past the last element of it. Hence `x` and `y` must verify this constraint and have type `unsigned char (*)[n]` or compatible. There is an exception to this rule for accessing any type as an array of character type, so passing pointers to the same array of `int` would be fine, but it would be incorrect (although probably harmless) to call `f` this way:

```
int x, y;
ptrdiff_t dist = f(sizeof(int), &x, &y);
```

Compilers are free to issue diagnostic messages to attract the programmer's attention on potential problems, indeed such warnings are life savers in many cases for beginners and advanced programmers alike.  Compiler options such as `-Wall`, `-Werror` and `-Weverything` are quite useful, but in this particular case, one will need to add `-Wno-pointer-arith` to allow **clang** to compile this function if `-Werror` is also active.

Note also that the same result can be obtained with a C89 function:

```
ptrdiff_t f89(size_t n, void *x, void *y)
{
    if (!n) return 0;
    unsigned char *a = x, *b = y;
    return (a - b) / n;
}
```

Comment: Why is it invalid to call `f` that way? Doesn't 6.2.6/4 (C99) make it
valid to interpret any object type `type` as an array of `unsigned char`
with size `sizeof(type)` (i.e. the underlying object representation)?
If you look into the edit history of the question you'll see of what
usage I have in mind for "element" pointers: inside functions with a
function contract ala `qsort` and `bsearch`.

Comment: "it should be fine" are famous last words considering this is C we're
talking about. And its in no way an authoritative answer... any
references to the standard would be much appreciated.

Comment: @nebel, yes indeed, I will amend the answer tonight.

Comment: Note: `int *` and `unsigned char (*)[sizeof(int)]` *are* incompatible
pointers. It's probably best if the parameters of the function are
explicitly cast to `element *` on assignment, even if `f` is in its own
TU (`int a; unsigned char (*b)[sizeof a] = &a;` is invalid code).

Comment: It's still not that clear to me if then an explicit cast is permitted as
per C's type system aliasing rules. It might be because from what I can
tell from 6.5/7 (C99) only access through that pointer would yield UB,
not in simply constructing a pointer to then only use for pointer
arithmetic. Thus, 6.2.6/4 might only matter for the pointer arithmetic
rules 6.5.6/9 stating "both shall point to elements of the same array
object".